# Form values are successfully stored to database, but IF statement won't execute after

Tags: php, html, mysql, if-statement, refresh

I'm having problems with my sign up form. Yes, it successfully stores information to my database but it just reloads the page(sign-up page) after and will not execute the code inside the if statement.This is my complete code(from the form and the php/mysql code):

```
        <form class="formoid-metro-black" id="close" style="background-color:transparent;font-size:14px;font-family:'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue','Helvetica',Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;color:#FFFFFF;max-width:480px;min-width:150px" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

          <div class="title"><h2>Basic Information</h2></div>

          <div class="element-name"><label class="title"><span class="required">*</span></label><span class="nameFirst"><input  type="text" size="8" name="fname" required="required"/><label class="subtitle">First Name</label></span><span class="nameLast"><input  type="text" size="14" name="lname" required="required"/><label class="subtitle">Last Name</label></span></div>
          <div class="element-select"><label class="title">Gender<span class="required">*</span></label><div class="large"><span><select name="gender" required="required">

            <option value="Male" style="color:#000000">Male</option>
            <option value="Female" style="color:#000000">Female</option></select><i></i></span></div></div>
            <div class="element-date" style="color:#000000; background-color:transparent;"><label class="title" style="color:#fff;">Birthdate</label><input class="large" data-format="yyyy-mm-dd" type="date" name="bdate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" style="color:#fff;"  /></div>
            <div class="element-separator"><hr><h3 class="section-break-title"></h3></div>
            <div class="element-address"><label class="title">Address</label><span class="addr1"><input  type="text" name="street" /><label class="subtitle">Barangay / Street Address</label></span><span class="city"><input  type="text" name="city" /><label class="subtitle">City</label></span><span class="state"><input  type="text" name="province" /><label class="subtitle">Province / State</label></span><span class="zip"><input  type="text" maxlength="15" name="zcode" /><label class="subtitle">Zip Code</label></span><div class="country"><select name="country" ><!--<option selected="selected" value="" disabled="disabled">--- Select a country ---</option> --><option selected="selected" value="Philippines">Philippines</option><option style="color:#000000" value="United States">United States</option><option style="color:#000000" value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Australia">Australia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Canada">Canada</option><option style="color:#000000" value="France">France</option><option style="color:#000000" value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option><option style="color:#000000" value="India">India</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Brazil">Brazil</option><option style="color:#000000" value="----" disabled="disabled">----</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Albania">Albania</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Algeria">Algeria</option><option style="color:#000000" value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Andorra">Andorra</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Angola">Angola</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Argentina">Argentina</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Armenia">Armenia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Aruba">Aruba</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Austria">Austria</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Barbados">Barbados</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Belarus">Belarus</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Belgium">Belgium</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Belize">Belize</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Benin">Benin</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Botswana">Botswana</option><option style="color:#000000" value="British Indian Ocean Territory">British Indian Ocean Territory</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Brunei Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Burundi">Burundi</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Chad">Chad</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Chile">Chile</option><option style="color:#000000" value="China">China</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Colombia">Colombia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Comoros">Comoros</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Democratic Republic of the Congo">Democratic Republic of the Congo</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Republic of the Congo">Republic of the Congo</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Cote d'Ivoire">Cote d'Ivoire</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Croatia">Croatia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Cuba">Cuba</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Denmark">Denmark</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Dominica">Dominica</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option><option style="color:#000000" value="East Timor">East Timor</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Egypt">Egypt</option><option style="color:#000000" value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Estonia">Estonia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Fiji">Fiji</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Finland">Finland</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Gabon">Gabon</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Gambia">Gambia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Georgia">Georgia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Germany">Germany</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Ghana">Ghana</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Greece">Greece</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Grenada">Grenada</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Guinea">Guinea</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Guinea-Bissau">Guinea-Bissau</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Guyana">Guyana</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Haiti">Haiti</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Honduras">Honduras</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Hungary">Hungary</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Iceland">Iceland</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Iran">Iran</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Iraq">Iraq</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Ireland">Ireland</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Israel">Israel</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Italy">Italy</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Japan">Japan</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Jordan">Jordan</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Kenya">Kenya</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option><option style="color:#000000" value="North Korea">North Korea</option><option style="color:#000000" value="South Korea">South Korea</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Laos">Laos</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Latvia">Latvia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Liberia">Liberia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Libya">Libya</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Macedonia">Macedonia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Malawi">Malawi</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Maldives">Maldives</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Mali">Mali</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Malta">Malta</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Mexico">Mexico</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Micronesia">Micronesia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Moldova">Moldova</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Monaco">Monaco</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Montenegro">Montenegro</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Morocco">Morocco</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Namibia">Namibia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Nauru">Nauru</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Nepal">Nepal</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Niger">Niger</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Norway">Norway</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Oman">Oman</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Palau">Palau</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Palestine">Palestine</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Panama">Panama</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Peru">Peru</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Poland">Poland</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Portugal">Portugal</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Qatar">Qatar</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Romania">Romania</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Russia">Russia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Saint Vincent and the Grenadines">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Samoa">Samoa</option><option style="color:#000000" value="San Marino">San Marino</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Senegal">Senegal</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Serbia">Serbia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Singapore">Singapore</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Somalia">Somalia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="South Africa">South Africa</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Spain">Spain</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Sudan">Sudan</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Suriname">Suriname</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Sweden">Sweden</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Syria">Syria</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Tanzania">Tanzania</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Thailand">Thailand</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Togo">Togo</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Tonga">Tonga</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Turkey">Turkey</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Uganda">Uganda</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option><option style="color:#000000" value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option><option style="color:#000000" value="United States Minor Outlying Islands">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Vatican City">Vatican City</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Virgin Islands, British">Virgin Islands, British</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Virgin Islands, U.S.">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Yemen">Yemen</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Zambia">Zambia</option><option style="color:#000000" value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option></select><i></i><label class="subtitle">Country</label></div></div>
            <div class="element-separator"><hr><h3 class="section-break-title"></h3></div>
            <div class="title"><h2>Log-in Information</h2></div>
            <div class="element-email"><label class="title">E-mail<span class="required">*</span></label><input class="large" type="email" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" value="" required="required"/></div>
            <div class="element-input"><label class="title">Username<span class="required">*</span></label><input class="large" type="text" name="username" required="required"/></div>
            <div class="element-password"><label class="title">Password<span class="required">*</span></label><input class="large" type="password" name="password" id="password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,}" value="" required="required"/><label class="subtitle">Password must be at least 8 characters composed of at least 1 uppercase, 1 number and  letters. </label></div>
            <div class="element-password"><label class="title">Confirm Password<span class="required">*</span></label><input class="large" type="password" name="password1" id="confirm_password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,}" value="" required="required"/></div>
            <div class="element-separator"><hr><h3 class="section-break-title"></h3></div>
            <div class="element-phone"><label class="title">Phone<span class="required">*</span></label><input class="large" type="tel" pattern="[+]?[#0-9]{3,}" maxlength="14" name="phone" required="required" value=""/></div>
            <div class="element-separator"><hr><h3 class="section-break-title"></h3></div>
            <div class="title"><h2>Profile Information</h2></div>
            <div class="element-file"><label class="title">Profile Picture</label><label class="large" ><div class="button">Choose Photo</div><input type="file" name="profilephoto" class="file_input" value="" /><div class="file_text">...</div></label></div>
            <div class="element-input"><label class="title">School</label><input class="large" type="text" name="school" value=""/><label class="subtitle">Name of last school graduated.</label></div>
            <div class="element-input"><label class="title">Work</label><input class="large" type="text" name="work" value=""/></div>
            <div class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up"/></div></form><script type="text/javascript" src="forms/sign-up-form_files/formoid1/formoid-metro-black.js"></script>

            <?php include("includes/db-connect.php");


            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
              $fname = $_POST['fname'];
              $lname = $_POST['lname'];                  
              $gender = $_POST['gender'];
              $bdate = $_POST['bdate'];
              $street = $_POST['street'];
              $city = $_POST['city'];
              $province = $_POST['province'];
              $zcode = $_POST['zcode'];
              $country = $_POST['country'];  

              $email = $_POST['email'];
              $username = $_POST['username'];
              $password = $_POST['password'];
              $password1 = $_POST['password1'];
              $phone = $_POST['phone'];

              $school = $_POST['school'];
              $work = $_POST['work'];

              $profilephoto = $_FILES['profilephoto']['name'];
              $photo_tmp = $_FILES['profilephoto']['tmp_name'];



              move_uploaded_file($photo_tmp,"includes/user/profile/$profilephoto");

              $userquery = "insert into user (`user-firstname`, `user-lastname`, `user-address`, `user-address-city`, `user-address-province`, `user-address-zipcode`, `user-email`, `user-username`, `user-password`, `user-phone`, `user-gender`, `user-address-country`, `user-birthdate`, `user-profile-photo`, `user-school`,`user-work`) values ('$fname', '$lname', '$street', '$city', '$province', '$zcode', '$email', '$username', '$password', '$phone', '$gender', '$country', '$bdate', '$profilephoto', '$school', '$work')";
              $dt = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $_POST['bdate']);


              if (mysqli_query($conn, $userquery)) {
                ?><div id='openModal' class='modalDialog'><div><a href='log-in.php' title='Close' class='close'>X</a> <h3>Thank you! You have successfully registered.</h3></div></div>      

                <?php
              } else {
                ?><div id='openModal' class='modalDialog'><div><a href='../sign-up.php' title='Close' class='close'>X</a><h3>Error. Please try again.</h3><?php $userquery . mysqli_error($conn)?></div></div><?php ;
              }



              mysqli_close($conn);
            }

            ?>
```

What I want the code to execute after inserting the values if the code inside this if statement:

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $userquery)) {
```

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not even escaping the user inputs!

Comment: how do i do that? (beginner here)

Comment: Click on the links in my comment ("Prepared Statements" is actually a link in my previous comment).

Comment: the examples use mysql which is deprecated nbow

Comment: No, it's not. It's using mysqli. You never could use Prepared Statements with mysql...

Comment: kindly remove the extra html from your question, just include the relevant stuff.

Comment: have you checked by placing the echo statement in IF and ELSE conditions ? if not first check it by placing in both of the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

**Description** Make use of the following IF Condition. As on successful insertion it will return TRUE and on failure it will return FALSE

```
   if (mysqli_query($conn, $userquery) == TRUE) {

      //YOUR Logic

   } else {

      //YOUR Logic

   }
```

Comment: If the query returns true... his old statement `if (mysqli_query($query)) {` should work as well...   _(btw... he's using  mysqli\_* and not the oop version)_

Comment: Your assertment `mysqli_query() == true` _returns_ `true` if the result from the function is `true` (or rather "truish"). Which renders the code you added `== true` completely unnecessary and useless, and will not change the functionality of the code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few points of improvement in your code, as already noted by many of the comments. Most importantly you must read up on SQL injections, XSS attacks, and all of the other common security flaws. [OWASP is an excellent source](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Attack) of information on this.

Secondly, I'd also recommend you to read through the [PHP: The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) site. It will be invaluable in helping you improve the quality of your code.

Then, my suggestions for your code:

```
<?php

include ("includes/db-connect.php");

// If a form has been submitted, attempt to create a new user.
if (isset ($_POST['submit'])) {
    $output = create_user ($db);
}

?>

<form class="formoid-metro-black" id="close" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="title">Basic Information</h2>

        <div class="element-name">
            <span class="required">*</span>
            <input id="nameFirst" type="text" size="8" name="fname" required="required">
            <label for="nameFirst" class="subtitle">First Name</label>

            <input id="nameLast" type="text" size="14" name="lname" required="required">
            <label for="nameLast" class="subtitle">Last Name</label>
        </div>

        <div class="element-select">
            <label for="gender" class="title">Gender<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <select id="gender" name="gender" required="required" class="large">
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="element-date">
            <label for="birth" class="title">Birthdate</label>
            <input id="birth" class="large" data-format="yyyy-mm-dd" type="date" name="bdate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="element-address">
        <legend>Address</legend>

        <input id="street" type="text" name="street">
        <label for="street" class="subtitle">Barangay / Street Address</label>

        <input id="city" type="text" name="city">
        <label for="city" class="subtitle">City</label>

        <input id="state" type="text" name="province">
        <label for="state" class="subtitle">Province / State</label>

        <input id="zip" type="text" maxlength="15" name="zcode">
        <label for="zip" class="subtitle">Zip Code</label>

        <select id="country" name="country">
            <!--<option selected="selected" value="0" disabled="disabled">--- Select a country ---</option> -->
            <option selected="selected" value="1">Philippines</option>
            <option value="2">United States</option>
            <option value="3">United Kingdom</option>
            .....
            <option value="71">Zimbabwe</option>
        </select>
        <label for="country" class="subtitle">Country</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <h2>Log-in Information</h2>
        ......
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up">
    </fieldset>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="forms/sign-up-form_files/formoid1/formoid-metro-black.js"></script>

<?php

// Now we can simply and safely echo the output.
echo $output;

?>

<?php
/**
 * Validates the input and creates a new user.
 * In case of errors it returns an error string.
 *
 * @param PDO $db The database connection to use.
 * @return string
 */
function create_user (PDO $db) {
    // We're going to need these ready to be used.
    $errors = $data = array ();

    // First off: Check that the data you receive is within acceptable parameters of
    // what you expect. Such as a name containing letters, dash, dot, and possibly numbers.
    // White-list only! You cannot know all of the bad stuff.
    $data[':fname'] = $_POST['fname'];
    $data[':lfname'] = $_POST['lname'];

    // Example: Test gender for M/F as those are the only valid values.
    if (empty ($_POST['gender']) || ($_POST['gender'] != 'm' && $_POST['gender'] == 'f')) {
        // The value is either missing, or _not_ one of the accepted values.
        // Add error message to the user here.
        $errors[] = 'Gender';
    } else {
        $data[':gender'] = $_POST['gender'];
    }

    // Since birthdate, and other, fields can be empty. Check for that as well.
    if (!empty ($_POST['bdate'])) {
        $dt = \DateTime::createFromFormat ('m/d/Y', $_POST['bdate']);
        if (!$dt) {
            // Not a valid input format for the birthdate. Add error message here.
            $errors[] = 'Birthdate';
        }

        // Just used an (so far) undefined constant here for simplicity.
        $data[':birth'] = $dt->format (MYSQL_FORMAT);
    }

    // Complete these.
    $street = $_POST['street'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $province = $_POST['province'];
    $zcode = $_POST['zcode'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password1 = $_POST['password1'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $school = $_POST['school'];
    $work = $_POST['work'];

    // Here you need to verify that the file uploaded is indeed a photo!
    // Not to mention that the upload was indeed succesful, and that other parameters
    // such as filename, length and so forth is acceptable.
    $profilephoto = $_FILES['profilephoto']['name'];
    $photo_tmp = $_FILES['profilephoto']['tmp_name'];

    if (!move_uploaded_file ($photo_tmp, "includes/user/profile/$profilephoto")) {
        // Failed moving (uploading) the file. Add error here.
        $errors[] = 'Profile picture';
    }

    // If we have any errors added to the array, abort and give he user notice about what's wrong.
    if (!empty ($errors)) {
        return 'Following fields failed validation: '.implode (',', $errors);
    }

    // Use prepared statements to avoid SQL-injections.
    // Also, moved the city name, province and country to their own tables.
    // This to avoid duplication of data and data integrity problems (typos).
    $userquery = <<<EOQ
INSERT INTO user (`user-firstname`, `user-lastname`, `user-address`, `user-address-zipcode`,
`user-email`, `user-username`, `user-password`, `user-phone`, `user-gender`, `user-birthdate`,
`user-profile-photo`, `user-school`,`user-work`)
VALUES (:fname, :lname, :street, :zip, :email, :user, :pass, :phone, :gender, :birth, :photo, :school, :work)";
EOQ;
    $stmt = $db->prepare($userquery);
    $res = $stmt->execute($data);

    // We need the user ID for the session, and to check if a user was actually added.
    $userID = $db->lastInsertId();

    // If successful, return dialog string.
    if ($res && $userID) {
        // I'd much rather redirect the user to the modal dialoge here, as it
        // would prevent problems with re-submitting data on refresh.

        return <<<EOF
<div id='openModal' class='modalDialog'>
    <div>
        <a href='log-in.php' title='Close' class='close'>X</a>
        <h3>Thank you! You have successfully registered.</h3>
    </div>
</div>
EOF;
    }

    // Not successful, return error string.
    return <<<EOF
<div id='openModal' class='modalDialog'>
    <div>
        <a href='../sign-up.php' title='Close' class='close'>X</a>
        <h3>Error. Please try again.</h3><?php $userquery . mysqli_error($conn)?></div>
</div>
EOF;
}
```

You'll notice that I've cleaned up your HTML code a lot. Seeing as you're already using classes, you do not need nor want inline CSS cluttering up. It'll only make things a lot harder to maintain, for both you and others.
Secondly, I removed a whole lot of unnecessary markup. As well as adding IDs (instead of classes) to the input elements, so that you can use the labels properly.
The third part was that I added `fieldsets` instead of `divs` and `hr`, to create the sections of the form. As you can see this gives you a lot less code, and you can accomplish exactly the same effect with a few lines of CSS.

I also changed the DB class to PDO, so that I could used named placeholders in the statement. Something MySQLi sadly lacks.

Perusing the comments and a thorough read-through the changes I made, as well as trying to understand/research why I did them, is recommended. Should you have any questions, don't be afraid to ask. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can redirect the user to login page.
For that case :

```
 if (mysqli_query($conn, $userquery)) {

          echo "<script type="javascript">window.location.href='log-in.php'</script>";
          } else {
            ?><div id='openModal' class='modalDialog'><div><a href='../sign-up.php' title='Close' class='close'>X</a><h3>Error. Please try again.</h3><?php $userquery . mysqli_error($conn)?></div></div><?php ;
          }
```

I did not find the modal related code in your code.

Comment: I used <link rel> to link the css file

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, yes you are right, I have already gave alternate solution.